# Advice simplifying my Architecture... asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, architecture

I currently have a UI Layer/ DomainService layer (domain logic and services reside here) and Repo Layer for persistance, I use **Ninject** to help decouple things.

I have kept my UI Layer very simple - which delegate tasks to the service layer, however I have a very complex application that depends on the loggedonuser, therefore my CRUD can get quite complex.

My problem though is: I have a service for almost everything and that then connects onto a GenericRepository.

For example 
IOrder which communicates with the IDBRepo to get order info depending on what client accesses the order, then I have IShipping - which also connects to IDBRepoand retireves info... it gets complicated when 1 service needs to call another service, they are both connected to the IDBRepo.

I have managed to pull out the IUserSession and can give this to each service - but this all seems too complicated to me...

When setting up my test I have to do something like:

```
var db = new DBRepo();
var s1 = new OrderService(db);
var s2 = new ShippingService(s1,db);
```

Then to extend some/most of my services I have to add an **ILoggingService** and **INotificationService** - they both need access to the database too...

NOTE: I am not looking for a pure DDD, I am trying to take the best of things and make it work I guess that has been my problem...

Comment: What's the difference between a UI component, service implementation or backend system invoking a service? The whole idea of services is to expose some function or data to any client. (I don't know c# or asp.net so I may miss something here)

Comment: True... These services reside in my core layer, the domainservice, to be honest I keep only services inside this layer, all other layers (db) will implement and provide the functionality for that service if needed...

Answer (score 0):

Bob Cravens truck trackr is a good series of posts to read to get you thinking about it:

http://blog.bobcravens.com/2011/05/a-net-generic-repository-pattern-with-implementations/

In general I don't think it's a great idea to have interdependent services if you can avoid it.  If you have to have it like that then consider using a dependency injection framework such as unity or spring.net or ninject.

Comment: okay scratch that I re-read your question and see that you're already using ninject.. the point is that it's better if you can design your layers so they don't depend on each other.  Logging, etc are cross-cutting concerns than can be AOP'd in.

Comment: The thing is My INotificationService is not really cross cutting - this is db driven, if some event happens send out notification, or is this cross cutting?

Comment: My IOrderService can be massive, and I mean massive if I dont split things up as everything is related to the order... to split it up I have seperate services for maintainibility also, however it gets real ugly when one service needs another to do something...

Comment: If the order service really depends on the notificationservice, then there's no way around it - you'll need it as a dependency.    The point is that you'll need to design your service classes to minimize interdependencies if that's important to you.  Don't forget about features like partial classes to help with this.